# Strange runtime error, seemly microsoft related

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, runtime, mingw

I am using the debug_new tool that come in the pack of tools NVWA made by Wu Yongwei. http://wyw.dcweb.cn/

I turned it off once to track a heisenbug, that now is fixed. But as I turned it on, my program throws a bizarre error:

It loads, but before accepting any input it quits and writes on the console:

"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information

Process returned 3 (0x3) execution time : 0.828s"

How I debug that? I have no idea what on the code is throwing the error (since when using a debugger it still quits the same way, and the debugger reports no errors with exit of the debugger being 0)

EDIT for those that don't read tags: I am using C++, compiling with MingW on Windows.

Comment: how is that microsoft related unless you're using visual studio.

Comment: This doesn't look like a MS error message unless you are leaving part of it out. (and is the error message really misspelled?).

Comment: When I typed the phrase on google, I landed on several sites that pointed that this message is thrown by microsoft c++ library. Seemly this debug library (that I never managed to make work on Linux) invokes some microsoft dll.

Comment: I fixed the misspeling :P
I cannot copy from the console window for some reason, so I re-typed it manually (but even the casing is copied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running under the Visual Studio debugger, go to the Debug/Exceptions menu and check the box for the "C++ Exceptions" item - this will cause the debugger to break whenever an exception is thrown.

You might need to fiddle with the various sub-options (`std:exception`, `void`, etc) for the exception types if your code throws a lot of exceptions that it catches and you're not interested in breaking into the debugger when they get thrown.

Comment: No, I am not using VC++, and GDB is set to catch all exceptions, but is not getting this particular one for whatever strange reason.

Comment: @speeder: You might want to add information to your question about the exact toolset and platform you're using since the answer seems like it might be closely tied to the tools.

Comment: It is wrote on the tags... Oo

Comment: @speeder: oops - sometimes I forget to check the tags... but even with that information, details such as the versions/debugger/'I don't know what else' might be relevant.

Comment: Windows XP SP3
Lastest stable MingW
Lastest library of the guy (the one that his page give download link)

Comment: @speeder: since you seem to be running into a fair number of roadblocks with this problem, you might want to try downloading the VS2010 RC or VC++2008 Express and building/debugging with that to see if it can help you get somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[KB884538](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884538) -- try installing the hotfix.

Comment: How I figure if the fault is mine or MS?

Comment: Ok, I am trying, but Microsoft does not help, the hotfix is only avaible upon request, but the link is broken, upon researching I found that people phoned Microsoft, but I cannot phone Microsoft because I am in other country.